Java API only partially available with Frida aarch64
I tried to attach with Frida to Java process run on aarch64 Linux (not Android)
I got that error:
using frida-server-16.4.3-linux-arm64
[Remote::PID::1234 ]-> Java.enumerateLoadedClasses();
 Error: Java API only partially available; please file a bug. Missing: _ZN6Method4sizeEb, _ZN6Method19set_native_functionEPhb, _ZN6Method21clear_native_functionEv, _ZN6Method10jmethod_idEv, _ZN20ClassLoaderDataGraph10classes_doEP12KlassClosure, _ZN8VMThread7executeEP12VM_Operation, _ZN11OopMapCache22flush_obsolete_entriesEv, _ZN14NMethodSweeper16sweep_code_cacheEv, _ZTV18VM_RedefineClasses, _ZN18VM_RedefineClasses4doitEv, _ZN18VM_RedefineClasses13doit_prologueEv, _ZN18VM_RedefineClasses13doit_epilogueEv, _ZNK18VM_RedefineClasses26allow_nested_vm_operationsEv, _ZN19Abstract_VM_Version19jre_release_versionEv, _ZN14NMethodSweeper11_traversalsE, _ZN14NMethodSweeper13_should_sweepE
     at E (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/jvm.js:146)
     at b (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/jvm.js:10)
     at _tryInitialize (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:29)
     at _ (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:21)
     at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:332)
     at call (native)
     at o (/_java.js)
     at <anonymous> (/_java.js)
     at <anonymous> (frida/runtime/java.js:1)
     at call (native)
     at o (/_java.js)
     at r (/_java.js)
     at <eval> (frida/runtime/java.js:3)
     at _loadJava (native)
     at get (frida/runtime/core.js:134)
     at <eval> (<input>:1)

client


 user@user:~$ frida --version
 16.4.316.4.3

Is there any way to port Frida for that process?

The Java support of Frida is not as good as Java Android support. Especially newer Java runtimes are not well supported. If you can try a different Java Runtime. There is nothing more we can do here.
